# Are there custom placeholders in Ulysses app?

Tags: editing, software, tools, ulysses

Does the ulysses app have anything that is useful for creating placeholder text?

For instance, if I didn't have a character name, or a place name I could do:

`{protagonist_first_name}`

or

`{placename_1}`

And then just do a search and replace.

I just wondered if there was anything built in that made this process simpler. (Keyboard shortcuts etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ulysses does not support placeholders directly and there are no simple shortcuts that would create a placeholder.

You would have to use your own implementation. For things to keep track of when using such a custom method have a look at my answer to the question [What should I do when I am stuck on names during freewriting?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/34129/23159) Depending on your language and your writing style you might get problems if you have for example nicknames or longer versions of a name and forget to change them. Or you could have problems with grammar rules.

[Here](https://ulyssesapp.com/features/table) you can see a list of features that Ulysses supports. The ones that might be useful for you would probably be to annotate your text with keywords and the classical Search&Replace.

[Here is a list of available shortcuts.](https://ulyssesapp.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Ulysses-for-Mac-Shortcuts.pdf)

To read more about keywords take a look at [this article](https://ulyssesapp.com/blog/2018/02/attachments-tips/). Basically this feature allows you to add meta data to your work so that you could annotate the text with a special keyword indicating for example "Prog_First_Name_Missing". As keywords are reusable this should be quite easy and fast to do once you've got the hang of it. To add a keyword you can press "⇑ ⌘ K".

For Search&Replace you can press "⌥⌘F".